# How to make an array on a curve always ending itself to the end of the curve (non-destructively)?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

this is a reallys simple question. 
how to make the count of this array of cube below changing itself depending on the curve length ? it could be done with drivers but it seems that there is now way to get the curve length non-destructively ? the non destructiveness is important because if i want to change the bezier curve later the array always need to end on the end of the curve.

[image: v]

Comment: There is a fit to curve option in the array modifier. It won't adjust the offsets, though.

Comment: If it helps, you can get the curve length with `obj.data.splines[0].calc_length()` (assuming the curve object with single spline)

Comment: thanks a lot. if thoses comment are posted as an answer form i'll tag them for sure !